# JMeter server agent not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have installed JMeter and installed PerfMon agent for monitoring CPU and memory usage. I run the server agent on my local host but not able to see CPU usage graph after adding jp@gc PerfMon metrics collector. All other plugins like jp@gc - Active thread over time working fine except metric collector. I also did telnet localhost 4444 it shows port listing. But not able to send commands like test or shutdown. It shows badCmd.

Any idea why? My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you checked the jmeter log? Either the jmeter.log file (or whatever you specified with the -j parameter) or in the GUI by clicking the yellow exclamation mark at the top right of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you did looks fine! But You have to edit your **jmeter.properties** file.

Please try to observe the JMeter log always, it will give you a better idea that what you have done wrong so far!

You must set  **localhost:4444** in your **jmeter.properties** file in the **Remote hosts and RMI configuration** like this:

[image: screenshot of jmeter.properties file]